# How to configure SFTP at amazon EC2 WITHOUT key file

Tags: debian, ftp, sftp, amazon-ec2, dreamweaver

My EC2 server running a Debian distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0

I need to connect dreamweaver to an Amazon EC2 instance but it is not working with keys. 
I need do configure my server to work without key pairs.
I want to connect at my server with a simple form.

Key pairs are secure but annoying. How can I do this? What modifications I do on the server?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942653/dreamweaver-cs6-ssh-private-key-sftp-on-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 1):

Set up an FTP service on your instance. You won't need a key, only a username + password. Make sure to open the appropriate port in the AWS firewall.

Comment: can you give me more details? I not work with linux very well..

Comment: @DaviReinoldo What distro are you using? Nobody will be able to help you unless we know what you're running.

Comment: I'm running a Debian distribution:
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0

Comment: Try this out: http://wiki.debian.org/Manual-Howto#FTP_Server

Comment: TY @Tanner! I installed the ftp Server.
I need help to create users and configure the ftp server now. Unintentionally abuse, but you can help me with this?

Comment: If you can snag a little more rep (you need 20) you can come to the Root Access chat room. We're getting a little long winded here. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: I have no 20 reputation yet..

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Tanner - Its a little vague to be honest, not even a link, to the wiki article you posted in your comments.  But based on how much effort the author seems to have put into this problem I upvoted your answer.